# error given in app when I try to start a level from main menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

when i run my game, the app crashes when I hit the start button to load a level. i don't see any error in the debugger console,my game uses cocos 2 d and x code. i get a break point here below. The thread 1 shows a problem at NS Object perform Selector.

please help i have one last issue.WHen i press start to load level the app crashes im getting no error:

```
debugger2013-07-17 12:28:06.554 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] main.m: Creating an instance of ‘Quexlor’
2013-07-17 12:28:06.684 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] KITApp launch started, iOS version 6.1
2013-07-17 12:28:06.885 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] KITApp window width is 480 pixels/480 points, HD=no, Retina available=no (enabled=no)
2013-07-17 12:28:06.886 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] Couldn’t load KITSettings, so initialized with defaults
2013-07-17 12:28:06.887 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] Settings init {
}
2013-07-17 12:28:06.890 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] Couldn’t load KITSettings, so initialized with defaults
2013-07-17 12:28:06.891 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] Settings init {
}
2013-07-17 12:28:06.895 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] Saved settings to ‘~/Documents/savefile0.sav’ {
iPhone = {
LevelObjects = {
RPGPlayer = {
};
};
};
touchMovement = 1;
}
AudioStreamBasicDescription: 2 ch, 44100 Hz, ‘lpcm’ (0×00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved
2013-07-17 12:28:07.181 QuexlorLite[1501:c07] KITApp launch took 0.50 seconds

im getting a breakpoint here:
+(NSString*) defaultLevel
{
return @”forest01.tmx”;
}
```

Comment: Try adding an all exceptions beakpoint. And enable "zombies".

Comment: Post the Xcode output of the actual crash.